# Italian verb for "to hash" in computer

Tags: verbs, translation, english-comparison

I'm looking for a single verb that translates *to hash* in the context of computers. Eg.

> Passwords in the database are **hashed** with SHA256

that translated is something like

> Le password nel database sono _____ con SHA256

Some verbs I was thinking about, but don't really fit:

- `criptate (encrypted)` I think this is more a two-way function, crypted text can be decripted, but hashed text cannot.
- `offuscate (obfuscated)` This is something hidden, but as above can be made clear
- `oscurate (darkened)` Maybe this is the best choice even if it's very similar to `offuscate`
- **Edit:** also `cifrate`. But isn't this the same as `criptate`?

Comment: I think that a literal translation would be _"rimescolate"_ or "_confuse_", otherwise, I would too go with "oscurate", maybe with a periphrasis like _"Le password nel database sono oscurate con algoritmo di hash SHA 256"_

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: SHA256 is an encryption algorithm so in my opinion hash you can translate it as crittografare. "Le password nel database sono crittografate con algoritmo SHA 256"

Comment: @Germano: thanks for your word. Unfortunately I can not find it in the Italian dictionary. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani: On the [dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crittare/) one can find "crittare" or "criptare", but not "crittografare".

Comment: @GermanoPlebani: But curiously, one can find  ["crittografare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crittare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) as a synonymous of "crittare"!

Comment: In theory you should use _decifrare_ to mean that you are reading a coded text by knowing the cypher used and _decrittare_ if you are cracking it. Vice versa, you use _cifrare_ to encode something using and cypher, while *_crittare_ shouldn't be used, since there is no such thing as encoding something without knowing the code.

Comment: And, yes, you should _cifrare_ only something that can then be _decifrato_ (or _crittare_ – but see above – something that is then _decrittato_).

Comment: With a heavy heart, I'd say something like _...sono sottoposte a hash..._, since hash, in this context, is something well specific, not explained by _cifrate_ or _oscurate_.

Comment: @DaG: though it's not a single word, I like _...sono sottoposte a hash..._ very much

Comment: "Decriptare" isn't cracking code but a synonym of "decifrare" = decrypt. In the same way encrypt = "criptare" or "cifrare"

Comment: I don't think that an English speaking person not acquainted with computer science would understand the term, which is normally used in cooking. There's no translation in Italian that I know of.

Comment: @egreg: of course, I know this is strongly context-related. Even an Italian speaking person without computer science background, don't know what an _hash_ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one word in your sentence, I'd say **protette**:

> Le password nel database sono *protette* con SHA256

Or if you want to make it clearer that they *aren't* passwords:

> Le password nel database sono *sostituite da(i loro) hash* SHA256

But both versions fall short of the mark when targeted to non-tech-savvy users, who might wonder if the *protection* cannot be broken, or where are the original passwords that were *replaced*. In those cases you'll be better served by the incorrect **cifrate**.

With tech-savvy readers you can concentrate on the hashes and forget the passwords altogether:

> gli hash (nel database) sono (**ottenuti|generati** con (l'algoritmo)) SHA256.

or more fanciful:

> le password nel database sono (sottoposte a|elaborate con|trasformate da) SHA256.

Comment: I like the word `protette`, simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no single verb, however the closest I can think of seems to be "calcolare l'hash". Indeed, searching for this expression with Google gives me about 2000 results.

For the example sentence I would say:

> Gli hash delle password nel database sono calcolati con (l'algoritmo)
>   SHA256.

Note that neither of the suggested possibilities (encrypted, obfuscated, darkened) seems ok to me, especially in this context, because with a hash you are not encrypting / obfuscating, etc., but rather calculating a checksum.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer because this one only describe the alorithm used to calculate the hashes, but doesn't imply security. eg. the passwords are stored plain-text alongside with the hashes